# Write vector<unsigned char> in binary mode

Tags: c++, binary, output

I have the following code (C++)

```
vector<unsigned char> bytes;
bytes.push_back('e');
bytes.push_back('P');
bytes.push_back('R');
bytes.push_back('f');

...

ofstream file(compiledFile, ios::out | ios::binary);
file.write((const char*) &binary[0], binary.size());
file.close();
```

but as a result is output file I have
"rPRf"
instead of bytes.

What I'm doing wrong? I need "65505266" bytes as a result.

Thank you all.

Comment: Have you tried seeing the file with a hex editor?

Comment: Yes, what did you open the file in, notepad or something similar? Of course a text editor is going to interpret the data as characters...

Comment: Yes, even though you've written the data out in binary form, that doesn't mean your text editor will display it that way.

Comment: what are you viewing the output file in? if you wrote ePRf to the file, then when viewed as text it will be ePRF. If you view it with a hex editor, you will see 65 50 52 66. If you want to see it as "65505266" in a text editor, you will need to write a text file (and will need to convert the bytes to hex)

Comment: How are you viewing the data?  A text editor will see 'ePRf'.  A hex editor will show you "65 50 52 66".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`e`, `P`, `R` and `f` are bytes. The file is 4 characters (bytes) long and it contains what you put there.

The only difference between a "binary file" and a "text file" is how linebreaks are read/written on Windows (and maybe some other special characters on very old OSes). The only difference between the character `e` and the number `65` is how the program that you're using to read the file chooses to display it. A text editor will display `e` and a hex editor will display `65`.

Comment: Sure I'm understanding the difference, but the only thing I want to get is bytecode in text editor.

Comment: @ICE: how many bytes long do you want the file to be? 4 or 8? If the answer is 4, then your question is in effect, "how do I tell my text editor to display the hex values of the bytes in a file instead of showing them as characters?". That question is off-topic for this site, and anyway you haven't said which text editor you're using. It might have an option somewhere to do that, or then again it might not. If the answer is 8, then your mistake is only writing 4 bytes to the file when you need a file of size 8, and I'll show you some code that will help with that.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you are trying to do?

```
for( unsigned int i=0; i<bytes.size(); ++i ) {
    file << int(bytes[i]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for clarification! Previous post is theoretical answer and this one is example.

Answer (score 0):

While I'm trying this

```
unsigned char * array = new unsigned char [4];
*(array)='e';
*(array+1)='P';
*(array+2)='R';
*(array+3)='a';

std::ofstream out(fname, std::ofstream::binary);
out.write((char*)array,3);
out.close();
```

it works ok, and in output file, using text editor I have only bytecode.